# How to pass the array of input data to Ajax function?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

In my input field name is like:

```
name="diameters[0][top]"
name="diameters[0][bottom]"
name="diameters[1][top]"
name="diameters[1][bottom]"
```

It's a two dimensional array.

I need to post this data in Ajax, how can I do that?

Comment: What you’ve described is not clear at all. This is a PHP array; it’s not clear how you expect this to look like in JavaScript. What have you tried?

Comment: this is my console output

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make it clear.

Comment: Edit the question.Plz check

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localised guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It often reads like a form of begging, which may attract downvotes. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize your form and pass that value in ajax.

```
  var form_Data     = $('#your_form_id').serialize(); 
   jQuery.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '<?php echo your_url; ?>',
                 data:form_Data,                           
                 success:function(data) {}

                 });
```